# How to Customize the Default Plymouth Theme in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, themes, customization, plymouth, uck

I've tried a lot to change my plymouth loading image!
I need to write my name in the place of Ubuntu!

Comment: Why do you *need* to? Will your system explode if you don't?

Comment: @Whaaaaaat , My system is not gonna explode.But I need to do ! Stop shouting ! I'm making my own custom operating system with Ubuntu !
So I need to customize the default plymouth !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you must do to get access to Root as admin is to open your terminal and type this code :

```
gksudo nautilus
```

(If you are using Nemo as the default file browser then this might be the code :

```
gksudo nemo
```

Type suitable code and press enter.
Then the filebrowser will be opened as the superuser.
Then go to Filesystem/lib/plymouth
....
In there you will find a folder named plymouth or anything similar.
Then open it and you will see some image files which works as the default plymouth theme..
Right click on the images you would like to edit and open with GIMP image editor.
After Editing completes, Just click File -> Save !
And close GIMP !
And Also the File browser with super user !
Then try Restarting your PC.
You will see the edited image loading !